# How to execute when include a js file multiple line on html

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, ads, dom-events

I have one file of Javascript used for ads service.
I add two ads to one page then Javascript line is duplicate line on page.

e.g.:

ads 1:

```
<script async src="//mydomain.com/js/ads.js"></script>
<ins class="myclass"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ads_1"></ins>
<script>
```

ads 2:

```
<script async src="//mydomain.com/js/ads.js"></script>
<ins class="myclass"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ads_2"></ins>
<script>
```

This case when html page start `<script async src="//mydomain.com/js/ads.js"></script>` will be execute twice.

How I can make it running once or other way for resolve this case?

Comment: That's not going to be possible to answer without knowing what `ads.js` does.

Comment: Why not just include the script file once but have it do whatever it's currently doing but to target **all** elements of a certain class, for example `myclass`?

Comment: @Mark_M my `ads.js` only send request to server to craw data client view.

Comment: @NewToJS Because this's case using for advertisement, 1 advertisement we have a block script code. we don't know how many advertisement client will be add to site. this's reason duplicate element script